# Issues with Flutter app using firebase on git

Tags: git, firebase, flutter, github

Pulled project from git and receive this error when trying to login/register on app ran on emulator:

```
[FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@5ac7136
PlatformException(ERROR_NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED, A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred., null)
```

Is this an issue with the firebase setup or with flutter?

Comment: not sure, but could it be the git ignored google-services.json in which case the Firebase project is not set up?

Comment: the google-services.json was not ignored so it must be another issue. Thanks for your help